# How to disable maximum camera brightness on Samsung Galaxy A10s Android 11

Tags: samsung, camera, android-11, screen-brightness, samsung-apps

In June, I upgraded to `Android 11`. In `Android 10`, you could set the screen brightness in the standard `Camera` app, just like in all other apps. But in `Android 11`, the camera automatically turns on at maximum <sup>screen</sup> brightness, and you can’t change it. How can I turn off the maximum screen brightness and make it possible to adjust it? I need this because I use my smartphone at the minimum <sup>screen</sup> brightness, and the photos are noticeably darker than in the preview. Therefore, in the camera, I also want a minimum screen brightness.

```
Samsung Galaxy A10s
Samsung SM-A107F/DS
Android 11 R
One UI 3
Samsung built-in Camera version "11"
```